# Doing action on last index of Camel aggregation split

Tags: apache-camel, dsl

Intention is to clear the class level attributes from the  EDI850Processor once aggregation last index is reached. But there is no property available to exactly find when we are reaching to the last index of split.

```
.split().jsonpath("$['ALL']").streaming().aggregate(AggregationStrategies.groupedExchange())               
    .constant("true")
    .completionSize(20)
    .completionTimeout(500)
    .bean(EDI850Processor.class, "process(*)")
    .marshal("edi850").id("marshal-edi850")
    // Do some final action if its last index of the split 
    .choice() 
    .when(simple("${property.CamelSplitComplete} == 'true'")) 
    .bean(EDI850Processor.class, "clear(*)")
```

Properties available on exchange:

```
{CamelGroupedExchange=List<Exchange>(30 elements),
 CamelAggregatedCompletedBy=size, 
 CamelMessageHistory=[DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=handle-EDI-processing, node=setHeader9], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=handle-EDI-processing, node=bean5]], 
 CamelExternalRedelivered=false,
 CamelAggregatedCorrelationKey=true, 
 CamelAggregatedSize=30, 
 CamelCreatedTimestamp=Tue Nov 05 20:45:03 IST 2019}
```

Which property can identify the last index?

Comment: Hi! The exchange property CamelSplitComplete (as described in https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/split-eip.html) is set, but because you've aggregated it will be in the CamelGroupedExchange list somewhere, not in your current exchange. You could try checking for CamelAggregatedCompletedBy=timeout, as that will imply you've reached the end of the split, but only if your stream is quick enough not to timeout while splitting...

Answer (score 0):

You could put your EDI850Processor bean in the step immediately after the split. Then it would be called after all the split/aggregate processing is done.

Comment: This will not work.   EDI850Processor  is part of split, if 10 split happens, this processor is called 10 times and and in last loop i want the to refresh the attributes of processor.